# How to read files from disk directly?

Tags: cocoa, macos, file-io, filesystems, format

One can, of course, use fopen or any other large number of APIs available on the Mac to read a file, but what I need to do is open and read every file on the disk and to do so as efficiently as possible.

So, my thought was to using /dev/rdisk* (?) or /dev/(?) to start with the files at the beginning of the device. I would do my best to read the files in order as they appear on the disk, minimize the amount of seeking across the device since files may be fragmented, and read in large blocks of data into RAM where it can be processed very quickly.

So, the primary question I have is when reading the data from my device directly, how can I determine exactly what data belongs with what files?

I assume I could start by reading a catalog of the files and that there would be a way to determine the start and stop locations of file or file fragments on the disk, but I am not sure where to find information about how to obtain such information...?

I am running Mac OS X 10.6.x and one can assume a standard setup for the drive. I might assume the same information would apply to a standard, read-only, uncompressed .dmg created by Disk Utility as well.

Any information on this topic or articles to read would be of interest.

I don't imagine what I want to do is particularly difficult once the format and layout of the files on disk was understood.

thank you

Comment: This is completely the wrong way to go about it! Why work out the format and layout of the files yourself, when the *filesystem* has done it for you?

Comment: Slightly more to the point: For what reason do you need to open every file? There (might be | probably is) a saner approach.

Comment: I don't need to understand the format of the files themselves...I just need to read their bytes, which will be passed through a hash algorithm. I do, however, need to know the layout of the files on disk. I assume this is possible since it is probably how a defragmentation application works. I really do need to read every file on a device.

Comment: And, the reason why I am looking for an alternative is that using fopen, etc. to open an read every single file is very slow and I need it to go faster. There are tens-of-thousands of small files and if I could read a few hundred in a single shot and pass that data over to a worker thread for processing, I believe it would go a lot faster.

Comment: *Every single file*?  You know that your average OS install is going to have *millions* of files, right?

Comment: Indeed. On my laptop, it is a little over 1 million. Why do you think I am looking for a way to make this go as fast as possible so my primary limit on speed is how fast I can get the data off disk? :)

Comment: Or, is there a way to ask the filesystem via an API where the files or file fragments physically are on disk?

Comment: You'd need to query HFS Plus structures directly. Have a look at [this tech note](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn/tn1150.html) for more info.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to minimize seeks. Are you sure that seek time will be your bottleneck? Also, are you sure that you want to read the contents of every single file, but none of the metadata? How are you going to handle hard links, symbolic links, transparent compression, and special files and folders like `.DS_Store`, `/.Spotlight-V100`, and `/.hotfiles.btree`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to look at the [file system format](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn/tn1150.html), however by reading the raw disk sequentially, you are for (1) not guaranteed that subsequent blocks belong to same file, so you may have to seek anyway slowing down the advantage you had from reading directly from /dev/device, and (2) if your disk only is 50% full, you may still end up reading 100% of the disk, as you will be reading the unallocated space as well as the space allocated to file, and hence directly ready from /dev/device may be in efficient as well.

However fsck and similar does this operation, but they do it with moderation nased on possible error they are looking for when repairing file systems.